# Bound on the variance of a product

Tags: regression, variance, random-variable, bounds

Let $Z$ be a positive $\mathbb R$-valued random variable bounded above by $M>0$, and $H$ an $\mathbb R^d$-valued random variable (seen as a column vector) such that $\mathbb E[H_i^2]=1$. Define the $\mathbb R^d$-valued random variable $B=\mathbb E[HH']^{-1}HZ$. Can we find a bound for the variance of $B_i$ in terms of $M$?

This is possible when $H$ is unidimensional, where the calculation leads to $Var(B)\leq 2M^2$. But I can't figure out how to proceed in the multidimensional case.